# проблема с размещением imageButton[] на RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android

я размещаю 36 кнопок по матрице 6х6 на экране.
между кнопками остается промежуток-белые полоски.
как от них избавиться может кто подскажет?
размер картинок в файлах png 66х106

[image: screen].

```
RelativeLayout rl= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl);


for (i=....
{
...
mButton[ind[i]] = new ImageButton(mContext);
mButton[ind[i]].setImageResource(drawableId);
mButton[ind[i]].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wb, hb));
mButton[ind[i]].setId(drawableId);
mButton[ind[i]].setX(x);
mButton[ind[i]].setY(y);
rl.addView(mButton[ind[i]]);


x += wb; // wb=66
y += hb; // hb=106
......
}
```

layout.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:id="@+id/rl"
                tools:context=".GameActivity"
                android:orientation="vertical">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Эти строки устанавливают отступы:

```
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
```

Попробуйте задать там нужные значения, например, "1dp" (или "0dp", если совсем не надо).

**UPD.** Попробуйте так:

```
button.setBorder(null);
button.setBorderPainted(false);
button.setMargin(new Insets(0,0,0,0));
```

Еще можно в XML кнопок прописать `android:padding="0dp"`

Comment: Эти отступы - от краев экрана, а не между картинками

Comment: mButton[ind[i]].setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(wb, hb));
может в эту разметку что-то аналогичное "android:padding..." добавить ?

Comment: Да, такие же отступы картинкам прописать.

Comment: как именно? ( применительно к моему коду).спасибо.

Comment: Добавил в ответ.

Comment: спасибо, но есть проблемки - Error:(145, 19) error: cannot find symbol method setBorder(<null>)
Error:(146, 19) error: cannot find symbol method setBorderPainted(boolean)
Error:(147, 34) error: cannot find symbol class Insets

Comment: Попробуйте View кнопки не надо задавать программно, а создавать из xml. В нем пропишите
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:padding="0dp"

Answer (score 1):

Проблема может быть в самом классе `ImageButton`, а именно в её `margin/padding`, кои могут быть заданы по умолчанию. ИМХО он вообще не нужен.
Попробуйте заменить его на обычную картинку: `ImageView`